# Did all Brahmin ancestors come through Kashmir , Gandhara or North West?

Tags: identification-request, brahman, skanda-purana, classification, kashmir

There are documents mentioning the migrations of the Brahmins. Does this mean all Brahmins came from the North? What about GSB saraswats? Are Gurjaras pancha dravida or pancha gauda?